# Beamer section title slides

Tags: beamer, sectioning, section-titles

I want to have a section title slide before each section (but not a full TOC), but I don't want the slide to display the default "Section 1" above the title, as does the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}     
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ latexsym }
\usepackage{graphics}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
\oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \usetheme{Ilmenau} 
 \useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
\title{Title}
\author[Author\hspace{2.5cm}]{Author}
\institute{Institute}

 \AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}

    \sectionpage
 \end{frame}
 }


\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{First Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the section page to remove the `Section xxx` line above the section title.

Some other comments about your code:

- missing `]` in your first line
- instead of `xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table` you can combine them to `xcolor={dvipsnames,table}`
- the `slidestop` option is outdated, use the `t` option instead
- the `mathserif` option is outdated, use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` instead
- you don't need to load the `graphics` package, beamer already loads `graphicx`

```
\documentclass[
%slidestop,
t,
compress,
%mathserif,
12pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usetheme[bars]{tree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}     
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ latexsym }
%\usepackage{graphics}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
\oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
 \usetheme{Ilmenau} 
 \useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
\title{Title}
\author[Author\hspace{2.5cm}]{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
  \begingroup
    \centering
%    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}\sectionname~\insertsectionnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,rounded=true]{section title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

 \AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}

    \sectionpage
 \end{frame}
 }


\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]